# How to inspect pop up windows/tool tips/hover effects which are designed to hide/close on mouse move with tools like WinSpy++ or Spy++?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, tooltip, spy++

Essentially I'm trying to learn more about the Win32 api, how certain classes/elements are created, destroyed, what items make them up etc.. Dissecting windows if you will for a project of mine.

I'm very curious at the moment what popups/tool tips/hover effects ubiquities to all windows applications are made up of. My main goal is to grab text from any tooltip/hover thingy/WS_POPUP?

If someone knows that is great but I'd also like to have the tools to research it myself.
I'm not even sure what to google to be honest to get me on the right path. I've tried some C++ code to print class names and fetch the text from what I think might be a msgbox but no dice so far.

Comment: Register a [WinEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/what-are-winevents) hook and take it from there. Though I'm not sure what sort of enlightenment you're hoping for. It's much more reasonable to expect a [good book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X/) to work much more quickly towards proficiency.

Comment: @IInspectable Yes thank you! I will probably pick that book up. Any other books towards this cause would be welcomed recommendation as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MiniSpy](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/1732/minispy) tool on Codeproject comes in handy in situations like this because it uses the corner of the spy window as the location, not the mouse.

Comment: Yes thanks! This seem to be really useful! It can grab the popup reference and now I'll just have to see how to use it beyond that. As once the hover leaves it doesn't seem to freeze the reference and loses it again.

Comment: You can perhaps modify MiniSpy by adding a timer button although just seeing the classname and parent window information while hovering is usually enough.